# How can I get the Thumbnail from Youtube URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, youtube, youtube-api

```
NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPwyVw_6vsQ&feature=youtu.be"]; // URL is a string which needs to be placed in @"" and close method call with ].
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:youTubeURL];
imageSel = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

I am using this code for getting thumbnail from the video and this return null value in the
imagesel.can anybody help me to solve this problem I am using YouTube URL .when I am using this code for the video that is in the main bundle then it is working fine.

Comment: You do know that MPMoviePlayer cannot play youtube videos, right?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII MPMoviePlayer play videos in my code i have done it from this link https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video/downloads and it is working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

Firstly extract videoID from Video URL Link.

Now refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/1106035) link for getting thumbnail of video.

Answer (score 5):

each youtube link has 4 thumbnail

```
   http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
   http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
   http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
    http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

this code is very good for

for example 
 i have this link:

```
       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPwyVw_6vsQ&feature=youtu.be
```

and the youtube video id is:

```
      HPwyVw_6vsQ
```

and generated thumbnail from this link is:

```
        http://img.youtube.com/vi/HPwyVw_6vsQ/1.jpg
```

this is very easy to use

Answer (score 1):

if someone wants HQ image use this link

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a YouTube watch page URL, and you want to get the thumbnail URL, the "correct" way to do that is to use oEmbed:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html

That way you don't have to attempt to parse the video id out of the URL.

But... what you really should be doing is using a `iframe` embed to display videos in your web page (or `UIWebView`). The YouTube API Terms of Service covers the supported ways of accessing YouTube content:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms